# String ID inside .RC file is not recognized in code

Tags: c++builder, resourcestring

I'm using C++ Builder 11.2 and have a following `strings.rc` file added to my project:

```
#define ID_TESTSTRING    1

STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    ID_TESTSTRING,   "Just for testing"
END
```

Inside my `Form1` (Unit1.cpp) I use the following code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    wchar_t resString[100];
    LoadString(HInstance, ID_TESTSTRING, resString, 100); // undeclared identifier ID_TESTSTRING!
    ShowMessage(resString);
}
```

The problem is that I get this 'undeclared identifier' error. If I replace `ID_TESTSTRING` with its numeric constant `1` then everything works as expected. Why the identifier is not recognized? Because, I want to work with ID's in my code, not with their numeric constants.

Comment: Identifiers are not "exported" automatically, or created as identifiers in all source files. You need to put the `ID_TESTSTRING` macro definition in a separate header file, that you include both in your resource and C++ source files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah, that did the trick. I thought I am not able to include a header in .rc file. Thanks!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that should be posted as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifiers are not "exported" automatically, or created as identifiers in all source files.

You need to put the `ID_TESTSTRING` macro definition in a separate header file, that you include in both your resource and C++ source files.

resources.rh

```
#define ID_TESTSTRING    1
```

resources.rc

```
#include "resources.rh"

STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    ID_TESTSTRING,   "Just for testing"
END
```

Unit1.cpp

```
#include "resources.rh"

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    wchar_t resString[100];
    LoadString(HInstance, ID_TESTSTRING, resString, 100);
    ShowMessage(resString);
}
```